# Use of "submitting" or "submit" in sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Why is submitting used instead of submit in the sentence below from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codebase?

> They are often used by multi-developer projects to handle various versions and developers **submitting** various patches of code in an organized fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***and*** there combines the two parts - ***various versions*** and ***developers submitting various patches of code***. In essence, it is to be taken as - ***to handle various versions and to handle developers submitting various patches of code***.

Answer (score 1):

They are handling the following two things:

1. various versions
2. the fact that developers submit various patches of code in an organized fashion